# Datanucleus/JDO InstanceLifecycleListener for makeTransient (or LOAD by query)

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I have a problem that i need to solve using **DATANUCLEUS** (JDO), maybe a limitation of something that was not covered by **JDO** specs.

I need to catch when objects are loaded in a Query - there is NO **InstanceLifecycleListener** for this! (Queried objects should be treated as LOADED objects after all - they can be changed, detached, etc)

```
Query query=pm.newQuery(...);
Collection col=(Collection)query.execute();
```

Another way to do it would be to catch when objects are made TRANSIENT. I found no way of doing that either!

```
pm.makeTransientAll(col,true);
```

Any ideas?

For detached Query elements, i use the **DetachLifecycleListener** over the PMF, that listens to the DETACH method. That's the only way I've found to make **InstanceLifecycleListener** work on queries.

Comment: JDO lifecycle listeners are defined by the JDO spec, so the best place to ask such a thing is Apache JDO

Comment: Yes... but Datanucleus could have a way of doing this as an "extension", or maybe there is a "workaround" to achieve what i'm trying to do, or even something i'm missing out...

Comment: DN bug? What versions are affected? Well, 2.1 RELEASE for sure (the one i'm using and STUCK with it because of behavior change of posterior releases): https://code.google.com/archive/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/210

Comment: If you are saying something is a bug then you have to demonstrate how something is a bug; all you post here is an arm waving "this doesnt work, that doesnt work". Facts are needed to make claims. And then you link to some Google AppEngine item (which is not part of DataNucleus from what I can see). I'm sure you'll find that the current version (of DataNucleus) is 5.2. Thought of using that?!

Comment: AS i said before, DN behavior was BROKEN after 2.1 RELEASE, that's the reason i cannot UPGRADE! I would, gladly, but i cant't...

Comment: I've turned on LEVEL 2 CACHE, and some queries already execute the postLoad method... then again, some DON'T (other seems to trigger only on foreign objects load, not the MAIN object). It's a real mess... :\

Comment: If something is "broken" then you can point people to the issue that relates to it. Strangely I cannot find anything of that nature when I search their issue tracker. More than that I have 2 applications that use the full scope of the JDO spec and they all work fine, and they run the JDO TCK on all releases and all pass. So I return to my original point, demonstrate something if going to MAKE NOISE.

Comment: What's the point? DN will never give support to version 2.1 that i'm using. Tried all i can think of to make DN 3, 4 or 5 to work under OSGI but can't! I just wanted to test if there is a problem with DN 2.1 or if this behavior is common to all versions.

Comment: You claim there is a problem with fetching and load callbacks. Such things would then be easily reproducible using non-OSGi testcases (using current releases) ... if they exist. Don't bother and you can easily get the code and actually work it out yourself.

Comment: yeah, you're probably right... just as DN was right when REMOVED "datanucleus.attachPolicy and said the default handling "should" work fine... (well, it BROKE my app and sadly i could never migrate to a newer version of DN and help with debug and improvement of DN). Anyway, a TEST CASE is not always feasible to do (i tried, believe me!) because the whole app is a test case itself! There are many scenarios that cannot be debugged in a test case, and even if they could, i'm left on my own because i SHOULD be using the latest build!. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i found out with a lot of DEBUG:

1) Queries DO NOT trigger any **InstanceLifecycleListener** (except when elements are DETACHED) if the **DEFAULT** fetch group (aka METADATA default-fetch-group) is REMOVED from the **PersistentManager** prior to the query. In other words: one cannot use the **pm.getFetchPlan().clearGroups()** method, or one has to ADD the **DEFAULT** fetch group back before executing the query. SO... if there is a need to define a programmatic fetch group, it needs to take into account that the DEFAULT fetch group will (must!) be present (aka, all the fields defined in the metadata!) for the **InstanceLifecycleListener** to work.

The workaround would be to **DEFINE the DEFAULT fetch group with ONLY the KEY** (it's needed) and just change the logic to work with that. What i did exactly... The result?

2) the **getObjectById** method STOPS triggering the **postLoad**!!! After debug i found that for this to work, the **DEFAULT fetch plan** MUST define another field apart from the KEY one!

There is a total lack of information about the way the FETCH GROUPS affect the way the InstanceLifecycleListener are triggered, and Apache JDO (at least) should revise the way this works (or at least the DOCS), so that JDO users don't go nuts with implementation.

Comment: The JDO spec tells you how things work. If you don't think the JDO spec description is enough then the onus is on YOU to go to the Apache JDO mailing list and ask, rather than rant on a third party site. I can use queries and get callbacks, when using fetch groups.

Comment: Me too, IF i don't remove the DEFAULT fetchgroup... Try pm.getFetchPlan().clearGroups() and them add your own fetchgroup... no listener is called. Since the DEFAULT fetchgroup has almost all or even all the fields (as per design of the app in question and needed to the persistence to work) i cannot LET the DEFAULT fetchgroup present, or that would invalidate the purpose of the fetchgroup i add programmatically...